# Text transform from behind the box

Tags: css, transition

I have a div element containing a paragraph tag of text. When I hover this div, I want the text to come out the div (from behind). I tried negative z-index but it didn't work.

```
.box p {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: top .3s, opacity .3s, visibility .3s, z-index .3s;
}

.box:hover p {
  top: -28px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: from behind ? how we can notice this ?, you can simply do an opacity transition

Comment: If you see, I have opacity transition too but it comes up over the box not behind it!

Comment: yes that's what i meant, by doing this how we can notice the transition from behind as z-index cannot have transition ... doing the z-index is usless

Answer (score 0):

Two problems. First, you have `visibility:hidden` in both cases so the element will never show.

The second problem is, the div has no height when the `<p>` isn't visible or hovered over so you can't hover over it at all.

To fix this to help get you on your way:

```
div {height:100px;}
.box p {
  display: block;
    height:300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: top .3s, opacity .3s, visibility .3s, z-index .3s;
}
.box:hover p {
  top: -28px;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

But that might be the ideal way for you and you'll need to adjust it.

Note that, on hover, you have `top: -28px;` so it's scrolled slightly off screen on the right hand side.

EDIT:
Another thing I want you to be aware of. z-index is not a transitional property. That is, you cannot transition from zero to 0.1 to 0.2 on your way to a rounded 1.0. z-index is an actual layer and you can only go in whole units from one level to the next.